# Dynamic GMM in R

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am dealing with large panel data, here is just my sample panel data:

```
Year  PERMNO   A    B  SIC
1991     a     3   11   2
1991     b     4   12   2
1991     c     5   15   1
1992     a     4   10   2
1992     b     4   14   2
1992     c     3   11   1
1993     a     2   9    2
1993     b     3   15   2
```

Dynamic GMM enables us to estimate the A-B relation while including both past A levels and fixed effects to account for the dynamic aspects of the A-B relation and time-invariant unobservable heterogeneity.

Specifically, I have the following:

A(t)=alpha+B(t)+A(t-1)+A(t-2)+controls+Year_dummy+Industry_dummy

Currently, I am running:

```
lm(A  ~ B + Controls + lag_A +lag_A_2 + factor(SIC_2)+factor(Year), data = data)
```

The reason I am not using "plm" is becuase normally we have to set the index:

```
pdata.frame(data, index = c("PERMNO","Year"))
```

However, my fixed effects are Year and industry, not individual PERMNO. Each industry contains mutiple PERMNO.In "lm" fixed effects can be implemented by adding factor(SIC_2)+factor(Year).

I do not know how to run this Dynamic GMM in R? I notice some people refer to "pgmm".

Comment: You probably have way too little data for a model of that complexity. And using lm when there is likely to be quite a bit of autocorrelation means you won’t be able to trust any of the statistical output.

Comment: Hi, I have large panel data and here is just sample data. My question is how to use pgmm or any other packages that work for dynamic GMM compared to my original attempt using lm function.

Comment: It appears this is not a coding question, but rather a statistical methodology question. Consider either stats.stackexchange.com or the SE Quantitative Finance forum.Suggest you delete here and then post an improved question with better description of the input data and some output of what you are seeing when you run some analysis. The you should get advice about what sort of terms you might use for searching with Google or in there environs for worked examples.